# Use CSS To Resize Elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, viewport

You can resize an element's width by its parent's width, but can you resize an element's width by its parent's height? (Without using viewport variables)

`CSS: "width=90%` of parent's height" ??

```
Width:90%;
```

The application for this is to keep an aspect ratio in an adaptive layout by setting both the width and the height of the element relative to only the height of the parent element, not the width. I'm trying for a solution that doesn't use viewport variables like 'vw' or 'vh' because of the spotty browser support.

Open to jquery, but would like to avoid if at all possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make your body or html tags 100% height and width and that will work exactly like vh and vw for the whole document. 
The parent has to have some predefined values of height and width so that children can take the form you want them to have.

Example.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {

  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
.child1 {

  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  border: 1px solid blue;

}

.child2{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;

}

span{
  display: flex;
  align-self: baseline;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <span>parent</span>
      <div class="child1">
        <span>child1</span>
        <div class="child2">
          <span>child2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to size the whole document to the viewport. I want to size both the height and width of an element to only either the height or width of the parent. Here's an example using viewport: width: 95vh; height: 95vh;

Comment: This maintains an aspect ratio by getting both the height and width from the viewport height. I want to accomplish this without using viewport.

Comment: can you provide some code to figure this out.. but if you are taking about some element inside a parent container. then you can just use % for that.

Comment: If you do " width: 90%; " it takes the percentage from the width of the parent element. How would  make it take the percentage from the height of the parent element?

Comment: Added an example for you to see

Comment: <head>
 <style>
  #red_square {
   background-color: red;
   height: 10vh;
   width: 10vh;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="red_square">
 
 </div>
</body>

Comment: In this example, the #red_square gets both it's height and width from the height of the browser. What I want to know is how to do this with just the parent element's height instead of the viewport's height.

Comment: Check the code.. i provided.. i believe that explains it. The parent container has to have some values, so that its children can use to define their height and width.

Comment: Now you got it. :) Thanks for updating that code. That is the function that I was looking for.

Comment: Yep, I checked your answer.

Comment: @BradChoiniere you should mark it as useful it it was usefull aswell.. helps me and helps others xD